# Hamiltonian flow vs Gradient flow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symplectic-geometry

A Hamiltonian vector field in a symplectic manifold is the analog of a gradient vector field in Riemannian manifold.

A simple computation using Cartan's magic formula shows that a Hamiltonian vector field preserves the symplectic structure, equivalently its flow acts by symplectomorphisms. However it is not the case that a gradient flow preserves the Riemannian metric, even for a Euclidean metric.

Why does it work in one case and not the other? I mean, I understand the computations, but is there any insight that can be given?

Comment: Which examples did you work out? If none, I suggest doing both computations with the same function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. Draw both Hamiltonian and gradient vector fields. Can you spot the difference? One will rotate and hence preserve the area, the other will expand, hence distort both area and the metric.

Comment: I worked out that example and I see what happens there but that is not what I would call giving insight for why the symplectic gradient is always a symplectic vector field while the Riemannien gradient is not always a Killing field. Did you try understanding the phenomenon beyond that one example?

Comment: Why are they comparable in the first place?

Comment: @ArcticChar They're perfect analogs. A symplectic form is the skew-symmetric version of a Riemannian metric (with the additional condition of being closed, that can be compared to being flat for a metric). A Hamiltonian flow is the symplectic version of a gradient flow.

Comment: Well, but we know that they are not comparable.... Riemannian metric has a lot of local invariant but symplectic geometry have none.

Comment: A flat metric does not.